# Some styles are off in React app after deployment

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment, material-ui, styles

I created a React app with create-react-app, and it works as expected in development.

However, after deploying the app, some styles don't apply.

I use Material UI, and most of the styling preserves, only a couple patterns that I noticed are off.

**Example 1:**

[image]

Here, the LOGIN button must be an orange outlined button, and the SIGN UP button must be a contained orange button with some margin in between. Here is how it looks in development:

[image]

**Example 2 - Some margins are not applied:**

Here, in between the menu items there must be some margins.

[image]

**Example 3:**

And Here you can see in the dev tools, that my styles are scrapped (for some reason the `width: 70%` is preserved though) and therefore not applied. Default MUI styling got applied instead.

[image]

Tried this on Chrome, Edge, and Safari browsers. All the same.

Tried googling, did not find a helpful answer or an article about the topic.

If you need additional info, please ask, as I don't know what else might be useful to debug.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` flag to styles that are not overriding.